# how can I use Crystal reports in VB.NET 2013 ( Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I already installed Visual Studio 2013 Professional version, then I download the Crystal Reports Runtime from the SAP site from this link

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

the problem now that I focus is when I go in VS to Add Item>> then I can not find crystal report item there even in Add/New Item/Common Items/Reporting 
It is the same question asked in this link [Crystal Report in Visual Studio VB.NET 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708918/crystal-report-in-visual-studio-vb-net-2013) but there is not an answer

What is the problem and what is the solution?

Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: Please i didn't get yet an answer to my problem. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a odd answer,
But after testing and trying multiple reporting generators

- Microsoft Reporting
- Syncfusion Reporting (looks a lot like MS Reporting)
- Telerik Reporting (just try it)
- Crystal Reports (very poor support and compatibility with newer Visual Studio versions)
- Microsoft Word (al lot of coding, but most flexible)
- PDF

I came up with 2 favorites.

If you can't afford to spend USD 500 for Telerik Reporting, I suggest stick to Microsoft Reporting.

In short, ditch CR and look for a better solution.
;)

Comment: Dear Ismail, thank you for this clear answer. If I grasp thats means CR doesn't support VS professional ? as I'm obliged to use it. I'm working on passage VB6 to VB.NET and I encounter this problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I meant that it's not very well supported on newer vs versions (2013 and up). The latest version is CR2013. 

On VB6 it was the only decent reporting solution. but it has shifted since .net came.

Btw, found an user guide that can come handy.

[link](http://www.crystalreports.nl/downloads/2.%20SAP%20Crystal%20Reports/1.%20SAP%20Crystal%20Reports%202013%20User%20Guide.pdf)